# comparing xmls in two folders(input and output folders) and displaying difference of each comparison using python

Tags: python

```
from xmldiff import main
diff = main.diff_files ("input1.xml","output1.xml")
print (diff)
```

Now this is comparing input1 `xml` with output1 `xml` and displaying differences in these two `xmls` else null in case of no differences !! 
What I looking for is ... list of `xmls` (input1, input2, input3....) are stored in one folder (input folder) and similarly list of `xmls` (output1, output2, output3...) are in another folder (output folder). I want to iterate through input folder and output folder and compare one by one each `xml` ....input1 with output1 `xml` and display difference , then input2 with output2 `xml` and display difference and so on....... 
Hence, all `xmls` in input folder must be compared with their respective output `xmls` and display whether same or if difference exist then display those differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With few modifition got the results-
for i in range(n):
        diff = main.diff_files("filepath\input{i}.xml".format(i+1),"filepath\output{i}.xml".format(i+1)
        print(diff)

Answer (score 0):

The methods for xmldiff seem pretty straightforward for comparing to xml files:
https://github.com/Shoobx/xmldiff

Your questions seems to have two parts, iterating through files and printing differences between corresponding xml files. The first part of the quetion is simple the second is much harder for hierarchical data.Differences are really in the eye of the beholder and I think you need to be more specific about what difference you're looking for. See: http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/115/1/1995-46.pdf

If your question provided accurate naming conventions i.e. (input[i], output[i]) you should be able to iterate pretty easily.

```
     from xmldiff import main

     n = 5 # number of files in each folder. We'll use 5 for example. File names should correspond for i in range(n)

    for i in range(n):
        diff = main.diff_files("filepath/input{0}.xml","filepath/output{0}.xml".format(n+1)
        print(diff)
```

I don't know enough about xml dff specifically to help you detect specific differences consider using `xmldiff.formatting.XMLFormatter(normalize=WS_NONE, pretty_print=True, text_tags=(), formatting_tags=())`

Comment: When executed this... Getting error as follows OSError:Error reading file 'filepath\input{0}.xml' : failed to load external entity "same path"

Comment: You have to literally input your filepath. My entry "filepath/..." is just a placeholder.

Comment: Yes , I had given the actual filepath..... For mentioning here , I mentioned with placeholder... Its throwing error as stated above.. !!

Comment: Did you use that backslash? Because that's wrong too. Should be "\" not "/"

Is your filenames actually in the order of input1, input2, input3... and output1, output2, output3...?